# Magento - Cannot remove css mouse over effect

Tags: php, css, magento, onmouseover

my problem seems simple, but I actually spent 4 hours looking for the problem and can't find it. I have a plugin in magento to show a banner slider in my frontend page together with an image below the banner. My issue here is that, the image below the banner do not have hyperlinks and still when you put the mouse over the image, an 1px grey border appears around it and it receives oppacity. I went throw every css file I found in my magento folder and could not find the source. Is it possible to use the !important feature of css to solve the issue here?

The website is here: www.lojaanalitica.com.br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your code style in this file http://lojaanalitica.com.br/skin/frontend/venedor/default/_config/store_default.css line 886

```
.main-slider {
border-top: 0 solid #dcdcdc;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
background-color: #dcdcdc;}
```

You can remove line with **border-bottom** option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is exact this, looking into chrome with more patience I was able to find it as well, thx a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

Past this css in the end of your style sheet.

```
.main-slider {
    border-bottom:none !important;
}
```